# Retrieving form params in Rails 4 controller using fields_for and accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I am positive this is the dumbest question but I cannot wrap my head around it.

I have two models in a simple has_one/belongs_to relationship

**registration_code.rb**

```
class RegistrationCode < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :billing_transaction
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :billing_transaction
```

**billing_transaction.rb**

```
class BillingTransaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :registration_code
```

In my form I am collecting information for BOTH models using fields_for.

**_form.html.erb (truncated example)**

```
<%= form_for @registration_code, :html => {:class => "form", role: "form"} do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :registration_code, "Registration Code", :class => "control-label" %>
  <%= f.text_field :registration_code %>

  <%= f.fields_for @billing_transaction do |bt|  %>
    <%= bt.label :transaction_amount, "Transaction Amount", :class => "control-label" %>
    <%= bt.number_field :transaction_amount %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

In my controller, I have the following.

**registration_code_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @registration_code = RegistrationCode.new
  @billing_transaction = BillingTransaction.new
  @billing_transaction.registration_code = @registration_code
end

def create
    @registration_code = RegistrationCode.new(registration_code_params)
    @billing_transaction = BillingTransaction.new # DOES THIS HAVE TO TAKE PARAMS?
    @billing_transaction.registration_code = @registration_code # DO I NEED THIS LINE?

    ##### THE TROUBLE IS ON THIS NEXT LINE #####
    @billing_transaction.transaction_amount = params[:billing_transaction_attributes][:transaction_amount] # THIS NEVER GETS SET!  NOT SURE HOW TO ACCESS THE PARAMS

    respond_to do |format|
      if @registration_code.save && @billing_transaction.save
        format.html { redirect_to registration_codes_path, notice: 'Registration code was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end

private

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def registration_code_params
    params.require(:registration_code).permit(:registration_code, :expires_at, billing_transaction_attributes: [:transaction_amount])
end
```

The params are submitted and I can access the params for the primary model (registration_code) just fine.  But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the parameters of the "sub" model (billing_transaction) and use them in the controller.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"ePpqwJkeTAGMzb5WRWeI6aYCx4xpqvq4rl2m405IbwLdbp9xE0RyPgTZ6NmX8SvCFu94GKrfMfV9PrOkKa1BLg==", 
"registration_code"=>{"registration_code"=>"HFmkbQEN",
"expires_at"=>"2015-07-16", 
"billing_transaction"=>{"transaction_amount"=>"958.40" }}, 
"commit"=>"Create Registration Code"}
```

To access the billing_transaction.transaction_amount, for example, I have tried many variations:

- params[:billing_transaction_attributes][:transaction_amount]
- params[:billing_transaction][:transaction_amount]
- params[@billing_transaction][:transaction_amount]
- params[:registration_code][:billing_transaction][:transaction_amount]

No matter what I enter I cannot seem to access that nested array of parameters.

Help.  Feeling super dumb right now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few important changes to your `new` and `create` methods as below would solve your problem.

```
def new
  @registration_code = RegistrationCode.new
  @billing_transaction = @registration_code.build_billing_transaction
end

def create
  @registration_code = RegistrationCode.new(registration_code_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @registration_code.save
      format.html { redirect_to registration_codes_path, notice: 'Registration code was successfully created.' }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

This is how the `nested_attributes` gets saved in the ***DB***.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I have adjusted my code to match yours but none of the billing_transaction attributes actually get written to the database.  Do I have to have a reference to a specific billing_transaction object in the create method?

Comment: @RobE. Can you post the log generated?

Comment: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xyz", "registration_code"=>{"registration_code_type_id"=>"1", "registration_code"=>"2UugNGaJ", "customer_id"=>"1", "course_id"=>"1", "expires_at"=>"2015-07-31", "original_seats_available"=>"33", "billing_transaction"=>{"price_per_seat"=>"29.95", "transaction_amount"=>"988.35", "customer_po_number"=>"4534", "invoice_number"=>"asdfasdf"}}, "commit"=>"Create Registration Code"}
Unpermitted parameter: billing_transaction`

Comment: I just noticed the "Unpermitted paramater: billing_transaction."  I will post my entire whitelist method (not truncated.)

Comment: `private
    def registration_code_params
      params.require(:registration_code).permit(:registration_code, :customer_id, :course_id, :registration_code_type_id, :registration_code, :original_seats_available, :expires_at, billing_transaction_attributes: [:price_per_seat, :transaction_amount, :po_number, :invoice_number])
    end`

Comment: @RobE. What happens when you use `:billing_transaction` instead of `@billing_transaction` in `<%= f.fields_for @billing_transaction do |bt|  %>`?

Comment: OMG that worked!  That was the entire issue!  Now I can access all of the whitelisted params through `@registration_code.billing_transaction` in the controller.  THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the hash of billing transactions:

```
registration_code_params[:billing_transaction_attributes]
```

To retrieve the first (and only) key/value pair in the hash:

```
key, value = registration_code_params[:billing_transaction_attributes].first
puts key     #transaction_amount
puts value   #958.40
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am really trying to figure this out.  However, I keep getting **"undefined method 'first' for nil:NilClass"** in my controller #create method when I just try to access those parameters using '`@whatever = registration_code_params[:billing_transaction_attributes].first`  I have got to be missing something simple.